# What is the difference when running a program via terminal and via Desktop Launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

I wish to launch a program in Ubuntu 20.04.

If I run it from terminal:

```
$ /usr/bin/eclipse
```

Everything works perfectly.

However, I wish to run it from the desktop icon, so I created a desktop icon script in `/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Eclipse
Exec=/usr/bin/eclipse
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
```

When launched via this desktop icon script (with mouse on desktop), some common features of the program are not working.

What is the difference between these 2 methods of starting the program? How can I make the desktop icon work the exact same way as the terminal?

Obviously, when I open a terminal, it "logs" me in as my default username. However, when I want to launch this unity launcher, I'm anyway already logged in with my user.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1431735/edit) and add how you installed Eclipse. If you installed using `snap` then the installation process should have created the `eclipse.desktop` file with all the needed parameters.

Comment: Eclipse was installed manually. But Eclipse itself works with the `eclipse.desktop` file, just I have also installed a plugin, which doesn't work when starting from the desktop.

Comment: Please edit your question and add all the information.